# How to logout of Facebook in angular app?

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using this Facebook module in my angular application (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-facebook). I can login fine and have used the module for several Facebook features. But I cannot seem to get the logout function to work. My logout function looks like this.

```
  logout(){
    console.log("logging out of facebook");
    this.fb.logout()
      .then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
       this.authService.setLoggedIn(false);
       this.router.navigate(["/admin/login"]);



  }
```

The console looks like this when the function is run.

[image]

But my app is not logged out of, neither is my Facebook profile logged out. I want to disconnect the app from my Facebook profile by logging out, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

install plugin

```
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/
```

then logout funcation call and clear local storage

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to use the library that I am using, and would very much prefer to not add a dependency to the project just for the sake of logging out.